# How to download a Docx file or msWord file using reactjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, download

I have been trying to figure out how can I create a download functionality when a user clicks on a button.

I tried to use the File save library but the result is not as expected, also I tried a turnaround and used a different approach but again the same.

When I download the file using the 2nd approach that is by using fetch API the file am getting is a corrupted file.
Please see the code below with the codeSandbox link as well.

**Approach 1**

```
const onDownload1 = () => {
    saveAs("../../testFile.docx", "testFile.docx");
  };
```

**Approach 2**

```
const onDownload2 = () => {
    fetch("../../testFile.docx").then((response) => {
      response.blob().then((blob) => {
        let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        let a = document.createElement("a");
        a.href = url;
        a.download = "testFile.docx";
        a.click();
      });
    });
  };
```

**Full source code link**

[Click to open in codeSandbox.](https://codesandbox.io/s/download-file-using-react-js-7znd3b?file=/src/App.js:284-603)

Thanks for the help and time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `"../../testFile.docx"` the app is attempting to serve the file from a relative path from where the app is being hosted and served from. The `testFile.docx` file needs to be accessible and served correctly.

- If serving file from the public folder

  Place `testFile.docx` in the `public` directory.

  ```
  /public
  +-/files
    +-testFile.docx
  ```

  Use an absolute path to access the `testFile.docx` file.

  Examples:

  - Approach 1

    ```
    const onDownload1 = () => {
      saveAs("/files/testFile.docx", "testFile.docx");
    };
    ```
  - Approach 2

    ```
    const onDownload2 = () => {
      fetch("/files/testFile.docx").then((response) => {
        response.blob().then((blob) => {
          let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
          let a = document.createElement("a");
          a.href = url;
          a.download = "testFile.docx";
          a.click();
        });
      });
    };
    ```
- If imported and used locally

  `import file from './testFile.docx';`

  - Approach 3

    ```
    const onDownload3 = () => {
      saveAs(file, "testFile.docx");
    };
    ```
  - Approach 4

    ```
    const onDownload4 = () => {
      fetch(file).then((response) => {
        response.blob().then((blob) => {
          let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
          let a = document.createElement("a");
          a.href = url;
          a.download = "testFile.docx";
          a.click();
        });
      });
    };
    ```

[image: Edit how-to-download-a-docx-file-or-msword-file-using-reactjs]